# Ng-select won't display selected item with @viewChild and Observable

Tags: angular, angular6, observable, viewchild, angular-ngselect

HELP: After user browsed back from `details/:uuid` remember & display filter that is selected before entering url above. I'm having difficulty displaying "remembered" filter. I don't want to use `FormControlName/ngModel`

Filter is like:

```
<ng-select
       #ngSelect
       (change)="onSomeEvent($event)"
       (clear)="returnToInitialTableState()"
       [items]="someItems"
       bindLabel="name"
       bindValue="id"
       labelForId="state"
       placeholder="Someting"
       clearAllText="Clear">
</ng-select>

...

@ViewChild(NgSelectComponent) ngSelect: NgSelectComponent

ngOnInit() {
  this.getSomeItems();
  this.locationSubscription = this.location.subscribe(x => {
    if(x.type == 'popstate' && x.url == '/some/url') {
       this.subscribeToFilterObservable();
    }
 })
}


this.subscribeToFilterObservable() { 
  this.someFilterBehaviorSubject.filterObservable.subscribe(
      data => {
         this.observableFilterOne = data.filterId;
         if(this.observableFilterOne) {
           var a =this.ngSelect.itemsList
                               .findItem(this.observableFilterOne);
           if(a){
             this.ngSelect.itemsList.select(a)
             console.log(this.ngSelect.itemsList.selectedItems);
           }
      }
  })
}
```

While trying to log selected one in ng-select event and inside ts method I unfortunately get the same result. What's bothering most is that both of them have `selected = true` which leads to question change detection (in my oppinion) or Angular lifeclycle mistake:

```
//(change)="onSomeEvent($event)"
onSomeEvent(event) {
  console.log(this.ngSelect.itemsList.selectedItems)
}

...

this.subscribeToFilterObservable() { 
 ...
 console.log(this.ngSelect.itemsList.selectedItems)
}
```

Browser console

```
0:
  disabled: undefined
  htmlId: "a2c971f2062e"
  index: 5
  label: "NANII"
  marked: false
  selected: true
  value: {
    id: "7f612ba9-be1c-4ac3-a0c8-952688ceb7a8", name: "OmaeWaMouShindeiru"
  }
  __proto__: Object
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

@ViewChild injects variable only when it's visible. If it's invisible, then it doesn't exist in the DOM, thus the reference variable will be null.

Use **FormControl** instead of **@ViewChild**.